# Microsoft azure Bot integrated in Teams sending respose twice using SSO for the first time

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams, manifest, azure-bot-service

I created a code in Bot-frame composer and published in azure Bot. We have used SSO(single sign-on) in the azure bot. Created a manifest file and published in app studio in MS teams. I am getting the messages twice  when I open the chat for the first time. What is the solution to resolve it.

Comment: please send some code sample or other detail - there's too little to go on right now in your question.

Comment: Could you please provide more details or any repro steps about your ask?

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT I created a bot by using Botframe composer and published in azure and integrated in Ms teams. From teams I'm getting welcome message that is repeating twice , it's not happening for the all the time , for the first time I'm starting a conversation with the bot I'm facing this issue. How to solve the problems. Please provide a solution for this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue there are two different approaches to solve.

1. Check whether you are using webhooks or not. If you are using webhooks, check whether you are having multiple webhooks with same ID, which could send double messages.
2. This can be some weird approach. Sometimes, microsoft authentication issue will raise and if you are still having issue after checking webhooks, kindly contact the customer support of Microsoft and ask them to reset the app secret key and re-deploy the application.

There is another reason behind this, because of the previous login issues stored in SDK can cause the duplicate messages.

https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/4387

https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/5798

Check the above links for reference.

Comment: We are not using webhooks for calling and also I tried to reset the client password and redeployed it the issue continues

Comment: ConversationUpdate does not send enough information to construct the data bags, and as a result the dialog state is not persisted. Please refer to the answer [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/4245) for a workaround. Also refer [this](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/5798)